# How to calculate Uptime from timestamps?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, timestamp

I have sensordata from devices in a **pandas dataframe**  for one month which looks like this:

```
timestamp                uptime

2019-07-01 07:10:00     504 
2019-07-01 07:11:00     504
2019-07-01 07:12:00     504
2019-07-01 07:13:00     504
...
2019-07-01 08:45:00     505

...
2019-07-30 23:59:00
```

The timestamps are snapshots for every minute and the uptime is **cumulative** and represents hours.

My question is how can i calculate the uptime for **each day**?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) by [`Series.dt.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.date.html) with lambda function for difference maximal and minimal values:

```
print (df)
             timestamp  uptime
0  2019-07-01 07:10:00     504
1  2019-07-01 07:11:00     505
2  2019-07-02 07:12:00     507
3  2019-07-02 07:13:00     510
4  2019-07-02 08:45:00     512

df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])

df = (df.groupby(df['timestamp'].dt.date)['uptime']
        .agg(lambda x: x.max() - x.min())
        .reset_index(name='hours'))
print (df)
    timestamp  hours
0  2019-07-01      1
1  2019-07-02      5
```